# Ios uiwebview crash

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

My app  use uiwebview  load web  pages, it randomly  crash , we can't reproduce it, 
the register lr is the same as pc,is it  stack was destroy ?

crash stack looks like this:

```
0 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000019557845c __os_lock_corruption_abort
    1 CFNetwork 0x0000000182f4c890 URLConnectionLoader::_loaderEvent_AckBytes(long long)
    2 CFNetwork 0x0000000182e791b4 URLConnectionClient::_internal_captureDataArray()
    3 CFNetwork 0x0000000182e78f24 invocation function for block in URLConnectionClient_Classic::_delegate_didReceiveDataArray()
    4 CFNetwork 0x0000000182f4550c invocation function for block in URLConnectionClient_Classic::_withDelegateAsync(char const*, void (_CFURLConnection*, CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMax const*) block_pointer)
    5 CFNetwork 0x0000000182e67ac8 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*)
    6 CoreFoundation 0x0000000183408cdc CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    7 CFNetwork 0x0000000182e67974 RunloopBlockContext::perform()
    8 CFNetwork 0x0000000182e67828 MultiplexerSource::perform()
    9 CFNetwork 0x0000000182e67654 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*)
    10 CoreFoundation 0x00000001834e0240 ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    11 CoreFoundation 0x00000001834df4e4 ___CFRunLoopDoSources0
    12 CoreFoundation 0x00000001834dd594 ___CFRunLoopRun
    13 CoreFoundation 0x00000001834092d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    14 WebCore 0x0000000191e04894 RunWebThread(void*)
    15 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000019557fdc8 __pthread_body
    16 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000019557fd24 __pthread_body
    17 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000019557cef8 thread_start + 4
 x0:  0x0000000170154214    x1: 0x0000000170154208    x2: 0x0000000170184030     x3: 000000000000000000
 x4:  000000000000000000    x5: 000000000000000000    x6: 0x00000001704882c0     x7: 0x0000000000000fd0
 x8:  0x0000000000019000    x9: 0x0000000026303831   x10: 0x0000000195f0b000    x11: 0x0000000300000003
x12: 0x00000001700768f0    x13: 0x000001a595f0df89   x14: 0x68a34dca3dfae422    x15: 0x00000000000000c8
x16: 0x00000001957d83b4    x17: 0x00000001840ba268   x18: 000000000000000000    x19: 0x0000000170154214
x20: 0x0000000000000001    x21: 0x0000000000000001   x22: 0x0000000000000002    x23: 0x00000001740afb40
x24: 0x0000000000000001    x25: 0x0000000000000001   x26: 0x0000000195c50e52    x27: 0x0000000195c5d13c
x28: 000000000000000000    fp: 0x0000000105ebaa80    lr: 0x00000001957d845c
sp: 0x0000000105ebaa50     pc: 0x00000001957d845c
```

Comment: Will you please post your code of loading webview ?

Comment: is it crash on debugging mode only or also when you run app in not debugging mode.

Comment: not crash  when debugging ,only find  in  release mode

Comment: @poojathorat 
NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUlr];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
-(void)dealloc
{
       [webView stopLoading];
        webView.delegate = nil;
}